# How can i get UID RFID to textfield form Laravel

Tags: laravel, arduino, rfid

so i have a project laravel with RFID. when i want to post data, it require UID form RFID reader. but error looks like URL not found on server? how can i fix this? can anyone help me?

this is my Laravel ManjmhsController

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('addmhs');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'uid'           => 'required',
            'nim'           => 'required|unique:mahasiswa',
            'nama_mhs'      => 'required',
            'foto'          => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg,JPG,PNG,JPEG',
            'tempat_lahir'  => 'required',
            'tgl_lahir'     => 'required',
            'kelas'         => 'required',
            'jurusan'       => 'required',
            'alamat'        => 'required',
            'email'         => 'required|max:50|string|email|max:255',
            'no_telfon'     => 'required',
            'saldo'         => 'required' 
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
            $foto = $request->file('foto');
            $ext = $foto->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fotoName = $request->nama_mhs . date('YmdHis') . '.' . $ext;
            $path = public_path('img/');
            $foto->move($path, $fotoName);
        } else {
            $fotoName = 'default.png';
        }
        
        $only = $request->only('uid','nim', 'nama_mhs', 'tempat_lahir', 'tgl_lahir', 'kelas', 
                                'jurusan', 'alamat', 'email', 'no_telfon', 'saldo');
        $dataFoto = [
            'foto' => $fotoName
        ];
        $data = array_merge($only, $dataFoto);
        Mahasiswa::create($data);

        return redirect('manjmhs');

    }
```

this is my arduino script

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN D2  //--> SDA / SS is connected to pinout D2
#define RST_PIN D1  //--> RST is connected to pinout D1
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  //--> Create MFRC522 instance.

#define ON_Board_LED 2 

const char* ssid = "DAVIAN";
const char* password = "gakdipassword";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);  //--> Server on port 80

int readsuccess;
byte readcard[4];
char str[32] = "";
String StrUID;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); //--> Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();      //--> Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); //--> Init MFRC522 card

  delay(500);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //--> Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  pinMode(ON_Board_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led On Board

  //----------------------------------------Wait for connection
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
  }
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If successfully connected to the wifi router, the IP Address that will be visited is displayed in the serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Please tag a card or keychain to see the UID !");
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
  readsuccess = getid();

  if (readsuccess) {
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    WiFiClient client;
    HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

    String UIDresultSend, postData;
    UIDresultSend = StrUID;

    //Post Data
     postData = "getUID=" + UIDresultSend;

    http.begin(client, "http://localhost:8000/manjmhs/create/");  //Specify request destination
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //Specify content-type header

    int httpCode = http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
    String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload

    Serial.println(UIDresultSend);
    Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
    Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

    http.end();  //Close connection
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
  }
}

int getid() {
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return 0;
  }


  Serial.print("THE UID OF THE SCANNED CARD IS : ");

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    readcard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]; //storing the UID of the tag in readcard
    array_to_string(readcard, 4, str);
    StrUID = str;
  }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  return 1;
}

void array_to_string(byte array[], unsigned int len, char buffer[]) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
    byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
    buffer[i * 2 + 0] = nib1  < 0xA ? '0' + nib1  : 'A' + nib1  - 0xA;
    buffer[i * 2 + 1] = nib2  < 0xA ? '0' + nib2  : 'A' + nib2  - 0xA;
  }
  buffer[len * 2] = '\0';
}
```

and this is my error looks like
[error monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiDlo.png)

can anyone please help me? thank you

Comment: 1) If you run a curl command to emulate your post request with `curl -X POST uid=xxxx http://192.168.1.7/manjmhs/create`, do you get the same 404 error? if you are, check your database and laravel, if not, you have something wrong with your ESP8266 code, and update your post to provide the serial printout you saw on Serial Monitor.

Comment: 2) Shouldn't you call `array_to_string()` function only after the `for` loop(i.e. only the byte array are filled with the card data)? BTW, your `array_to_string` function isn't necessary, you could convert a byte array to a String object with `StrUID = String((char*)readcard));`. I would suggest that you find a good Arduino tutorial and learn the fundamental of data types.

Comment: i have updated my problem in line //Post Data. the result in serial monitor is UID and -1 ? and the textfield in laravel didn't catch the UID